# How to deal with millions queries to DNS server?

Tags: dns, udp, client-server

I'm wondering, how modern DNS servers dealing with millions queries per second, due to the fact that **txnid** field is **uint16** type?

Let me explain. There is intermediate server, from one side clients sending to it DNS requests, and from other side server itself sending requests to upper DNS server (8.8.8.8 for example). So the thing is, that according to DNS protocol there is field **txnid** in the DNS header, which should be unchanged during request and response. Obviously, that intermediate DNS server with multiple clients replace this value with it's **own txnid value** (which is a counter), then sends request to external DNS server and after resolving replace this value back to client's one. And all of this will work fine for 65535 simultaneous requests due to **uint16** field type. But what if we have hundreds of millions of them like Google DNS servers?

Comment: There is also the source port. And if TCP is used there is the related TCP connection which is not only source port but also TCP sequence numbers. And additionally the original question is included in the response.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, don't really understand about using ports for additional bits. Ok, for incoming connections from clients we have source port number. And for outgoing connections to google server we have **only single port**. So how to identify resolved request from external DNS server to the client with that?

Comment: *"And for outgoing connections to google server we have only single port."* - No. The destination port is fixed but the source port is some random source port on the system of the intermediate server.

Answer (score 2):

Going from your Google DNS server example:

1. In mid-2018 their servers were handling [1.2 trillion queries-per-day](https://security.googleblog.com/2018/08/google-public-dns-turns-8888-years-old.html), extrapolating that growth says their service is currently handling ~20 million queries-per-second
2. They say that successful resolution of a [cache-miss takes ~130ms](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/performance), but taking timeouts into account pushes the average time up to ~400ms
3. I can't find any numbers on what their cache-hit rates are like, but I'd assume it's more than 90%.  And presumably it increases with the popularity of their service

Putting the above together (`2e7 * 0.4 * (1-0.9)`) we get ~1M transactions active at any one time.  So you have to find **at least** 20 bits of state somewhere.  16 bits comes for free because of the `txnid` field.  As Steffen points out you can also use port numbers, which might give you another ~15 bits of state.  Just these two sources give you more than enough state to run something orders of magnitude bigger than Google's DNS system.

That said, you could also just relegate transaction IDs to preventing any cache-poisoning attacks, i.e. reject any answers where the txnid doesn't match the inflight query for that question.  If this check passes, then add the answer to the cache and resume any waiting clients.

Comment: Don't really understand about using ports for additional bits. Ok, for incoming connections from clients we have source port number. And for outgoing connections to google server we have **only single port**. So how to identify resolved request from external DNS server to the client with that?

Comment: @AlekDepler you can open many ports (i.e. local sockets) to talk to upstream servers, each one gives you `txnid` bits of state.  there are 2^16 UDP ports (some will already be used, hence me saying 15 bits above), so you get ~31 bits of state even if you are just talking to a single upstream server.  you could just use the combination of `(txnid, sockfd)` (maybe also including the peer address for even more state), or look at the actual data in the question part of the packet (which you probably want to do anyway for correctness/security reasons)